# VSCode: Python virtual environments not automatically activating in integrated terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently installed VSCode and noticed that the Python virtual environments are not automatically activating when I open the integrated terminal.

From the information available within VSCode in this link:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/wiki/Activate-Environments-in-Terminal-Using-Environment-Variables

it appears that the Python extension may not be contributing to the terminal's environment.

I've attached a screenshot below that illustrates the issue:

[image]

1. Selecting "Command Prompt" from the terminal options within VSCode.
2. The Python extension notification indicates its functionality: it's supposed to automatically activate all terminals using the chosen environment, regardless of whether the environment's name appears in the terminal prompt.
3. In the "Terminal Environment Changes" section on my system , only the git extension seems to contribute to this terminal.
4. Examining the environment variables on my system, I notice that variables associated with Python packages are absent; only those related to git are visible.
5. For reference, the screenshot depicts the expected "Terminal Environment Changes" as per the provided link. This correct configuration, seen in step 5, is notably missing from the current setup on my system, as observed in step 4.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: What does your terminal look like? Show your virtual environment and describe where you see it not being activated?
There is no `show environment contributions` in my case, but it is obvious that the terminal has activated the virtual environment.

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason the problem is gone now. I don't even see the message i marked in the screenshot in mark 2. I checked in the python extension and i see there was a release yesterday. maybe that solved it.. How to close this question?

Comment: You can answer and accept the answer. Or just close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gone. Probably after auto update of the python package yesterday.

Comment: dont forget to accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.